# Can't start a cloned react app

Tags: reactjs, npm

*I just cloned a react app to my local computer from github, but when I go to run an npm start on it, I get this error:*

```
   ➜  sweet-movie-app git:(master) npm start
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:596
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/utils/unsupported.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:19:21
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:145:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
```

*I am not sure if it is something that is missing globally, or if it is something wrong with the local repo or npm.*
*Package.json*

```
{
  "name": "sweet-movie-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.0",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have to clone the repo, run `npm install`, and then the `npm start` command. Have you installed the dependencies?

Comment: I get the same error when I run npm install.

Comment: `nvm use` then `npm i` then `npm start`

Comment: It might help to provide the package.json file of the repo you cloned if you really get **that exact error** when running `npm install`

Comment: I added the package.json

Comment: It looks like any command i do with npm isn't working. Should I just reinstall npm?

Comment: Please check if any module is there in files and that isn't included in package.json. 
This is possibility.

Answer (score 8):

Once you cloned the git repository try to install all modules using `npm install` from the directory of your app to avoid these kind of issues.

Answer (score 3):

After cloning a repo, run `npm install` from your terminal in the directory which contains `package.json` file; this will install all the dependencies required for your application. Then run `npm start`.

Answer (score 2):

When you clone the repository, run `npm install` from the project directory, and then `npm start`. This happens because the dependencies were not installed.

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to run react app cloned from github, follow these steps.

1. First delete the package-lock.json
2. Then run this command `npm install` to install all the dependencies.
3. Then just make sure you are using **lts** version of nodejs
4. Then after completing above process, run `npm start`
5. DONE :)